# AMPSCRIPT IF Statement Evaluation

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Update:

I tried as suggested and made a couple changes:

SET Debug = 0 in each of the Source = "source1/2" statements (I believe that was your intention, otherwise Debug never = 0, and the lower IF statement never runs
I also added the output statements immediately below the IF Debug == 0 block to give visibility to attribute values upon page load.
enter code here
The output when first loading the landing page:

```
@FormSubmit: 
@Source: source1
@DataExt: ENT.source1_DE
@Error: 0
@Company: 
@Email:
```

After submitting the form:

```
@FormSubmit: True
@Source: 
@DataExt: 
@Error: 1
@Company: 
@Email: test@test.com
```

So, upon page load Source's value is "source1" and DataExt takes on the desired value assignment. However, after the form is submitted, the Source and DataExt values empty and Debug is reset to 1. Why are Source and DataExt values cleared after the form submits?

---

I have an IF statement that looks at a Data Extension's attribute value to determine how to set a variable that contains the name/location of a different Data Extension that needs to be referenced in a lookup function after a form is submitted. Here's the important parts of the code:

```
SET @FormSubmit = RequestParameter("FormSubmit") 

IF AttributeValue("source") == "source1" THEN
    SET @DataExt = "ENT.source1_DE"
ELSEIF AttributeValue("source") == "source2" THEN
    SET @DataExt = "ENT.source2_DE"
ELSE
    SET @DataExt = "error"
ENDIF

IF @FormSubmit == "true" THEN 
    SET @Company = Lookup(@DataExt,"Company","Email",@email)
    UpsertData("ENT.form_data","Company",@Company.....)
ENDIF
```

In this example, I know the attribute for `source` is in fact `source1` since all the values in the sending data extension are `source1`, and the following AMPScript in the HTML portion of the page returns a `match`

```
%%[
   IF @source== "source1" THEN 
      SET @Output = "Match!" 
   ELSE 
     SET @Output = "NO MATCH" 
   ENDIF
]%%
%%=v(@Output)=%%
```

The error message that's returned upon form submission is:

> invalid data extension reference. No data extension was found with the
>   specified name Data Extension Name: error

Can anyone explain why the IF statement is not matching `AttributeValue("source")` to `source1` in the AMPScript?

Comment: Are your `source1_DE` and `source2_DE` data extensions are in a parent business unit or shared folder?  And this code executes in a child business unit?

Comment: Correct, source1_DE and source2_DE are contained within a shared folder and the code is executing in a child business unit

Comment: It turns out that the "personalized URL" setting was the culprit.  While the page first loads with URL .../page.aspx?qs=[long string] (I'm using the microsite linking feature in the email content), after the form submits the new URL is my personalized URL .../[friendly_name].  I guess this causes the ampscript attribute values to be wiped after form submission.  I turned off URL personalization and everything works now.  Is there a way to make this work with URL personalization turned on?

Comment: You have to pass those values as hidden inputs in the form.

Answer (score 0):

I bet the error is likely that during initial validation it is looking for a DE named 'error' when validating the code, despite the fact that the lookup to this DE won't be run.  Try setting it to an existing DE and just have the lookup in an IF state to not run unless source 1 or 2.

E.g.

```
SET @FormSubmit = RequestParameter("FormSubmit") 

IF AttributeValue("source") == "source1" THEN
    SET @DataExt = "ENT.source1_DE"
ELSEIF AttributeValue("source") == "source2" THEN
    SET @DataExt = "ENT.source2_DE"
ELSE
    SET @DataExt = "ENT.source2_DE"
    SET @error = "error"
ENDIF

IF @FormSubmit == "true" AND @error != "error" THEN 
    SET @Company = Lookup(@DataExt,"Company","Email",@email)
    UpsertData("ENT.form_data","Company",@Company.....)
ENDIF
```

Comment: The error is in fact due to there not being a DE named 'error'; for whatever reason the IF statement should be matching the 1st condition (source1), but is being assigned to "error" in the fallback condition.

I tried your suggestion anyways, and the page no longer throws an error.  I'm not sure how to validate what's actually happening, but I'm pretty sure @error is being set to "error" in the ELSE section, and the IF statement containing the Lookup and UpsertData function is not running (no form data in the source2_DE Data Extension.

Comment: I would take Adam's advice and debug to find the disconnect

Answer (score 0):

Taking @Gortonington's suggestion a little further, I'd output the variables like this and check for proper values:

```
%%[
var @formSubmit, @dataExt, @source, @error, @debug, @company, @email

set @debug = 1
set @error = 0

set @formSubmit = RequestParameter("formSubmit") 
set @source = AttributeValue("source")
set @email = AttributeValue("email") 

if not empty(@formSubmit) then

    if not empty(@source) then

        if @source == "source1" THEN
            set @DataExt = "ENT.source1_DE"
        elseif @source == "source2" THEN
            set @DataExt = "ENT.source2_DE"
        else
            set @error = 1
        endif

    else

      set @error = 1

    endif

    if @debug == 0 then 

        if @formSubmit == "true" and @error == 0 and not empty(@email) THEN 
            set @Company = Lookup(@DataExt,"Company","Email", @email)
            UpsertData("ENT.form_data","Company", @Company)
        endif

    else

        output(concat("<br>@formSubmit: ", @formSubmit))
        output(concat("<br>@DataExt: ", @DataExt))
        output(concat("<br>@error: ", @error))
        output(concat("<br>@company: ", @company))
        output(concat("<br>@email: ", @email))

    endif 

endif 

]%%
```

Comment: Updated my example to check for form submission first.